# Corss-Platform JSON stereotyping / Serializer reacting on type-attribute? (Java/Objective-C)

Tags: java, objective-c, json, serialization, json.net

We've gotten a .NET project and want to serialize and deserialize JSON in .NET, Java and Objective-C.  Unfortunately, we've got the following situation: one attribute in the data model maps to 4 other classes that all inherit from the same base class. Hence, when receiving the not-stereotyped JSON format, we don't know which type to serialize one of these 4 objects to.

As a solution, we want to integrate a "type"-attribute, telling the serializer which class to serialize the object to. JSON.NET actually supports this: http://json.codeplex.com/discussions/56031

We're now looking for experiences of other developers with serializers/deserializers on the Java and Objective-C platform. Is there any chance to modify these serializers in a way that it reacts on the type-attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Gson for java support it too. I have same problem and solve it with custom serializer/deserialized. All you have to do: implements your serializer/deserializer and register it in GsonBuilder. Read about it [here](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization).

Comment: Thanks for that! Now I only need a hint for Objective-C :)